# Unicode range of Chinese characters (minimum viable)

Tags: unicode, chinese-locale

I'm making a game that needs to be translated into Chinese. I'm making custom bitmap fonts for Chinese. I need unicode ranges for the Chinese "alphabet". I want to compact this as much as possible. I don't need the symbol for "pen" during the Han dynasty.

I've got this so far:

0x4E00-0x62FF, 0x6300-0x77FF, 0x7800-0x8CFF, 0x8D00-0x9FCC

But it's enormous at 20k characters.

Can I compact this in any way?

Comment: Why not doing the inverse way? Get the strings, and then find the character you need. I assume you do not need many common and less common characters.

Comment: Yes, that's not a bad idea, I'll think about that...